# How to stop file upload at specific javascript event in uploadify

Tags: php, uploadify

I have below code. Upload is working fine. Now when I don't enter video title and select video file to upload, it gives me javascript message to enter video title but there after immediately start video upload via uploadify. So I want to stop video upload process if video title is not selected. Please help on this issue.

```
function frm_add_validateform()
{
    with(document.frm_add)
    {
        if(trim(txt_title.value)=="")
        {
            alert("Please enter video clip title.");
            txt_title.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

<form name="frm_add" action="video_clip_add_p.php?pkid=<?php print($int_pkid);?>" method="post" onSubmit="return frm_add_validateform();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="txt_title" name="txt_title" class="clsTextBox" size="100" maxlength="100">
<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" placeholder="Select your file to upload">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function frm_add_validateform()
    {
        with(document.frm_add)
        {
            if(trim(txt_title.value)=="")
            {
                alert("Please enter video clip title.");
                txt_title.focus();
                $('#file_upload').uploadify('stop'); //stop video upload
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```